# Error import m2m widget django import-export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm using a django-import-export Django library, but it's not working for m2m relationships.

I have the following **models.py**:

```
class Writer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nome', max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Sobrenome', max_length=50, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.last_name,self.name)


class Book(models.Model):

    book = models.CharField(verbose_name='Título', max_length=200)
    isbn = models.CharField(verbose_name='ISBN:',max_length=13,help_text='13 Caracteres')
    writer = models.ManyToManyField('Writer', verbose_name='Escritor(es)')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book

    # Cria uma string a partir dos 3 primeiros nomes de autores (se existe)
    def display_writer(self):
        """
        Creates a string for the Genre. This is required to display genre in Admin.
        """
        return ', '.join([ writer.name for writer in self.writer.all()[:3] ])
    display_writer.short_description = 'Writer'
```

O arquivo de **resources.py**:

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.fields import Field
from import_export.widgets import ManyToManyWidget
from .models import Book, Writer

class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    writer = Field(column_name='writer', attribute='writer', widget=ManyToManyWidget(Writer,separator=',', field='name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        skip_unchanged = True 
        report_skipped = False
        import_id_fields = ( 'isbn' ,) 
        fields = ('isbn', 'book', 'writer', )
```

When importing a csv file, it does not give errors, but it does not matter the data of the m2m field.

Follows examples of the data in the csv file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZouPI.png)

Comment: What does the csv data look like?

Comment: The reason might be because you are setting `skip_unchanged` to `true`. Could you try by changing the data or by setting the flag to false.

Comment: @HåkenLid, include up the csv data image.

Comment: @Sagar 
I did the test configuring it as false but continued importing without the data from the field "writer".

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `skip_unchanged = True`.  This may seem unintuitive, but it should read `skip_unchanged = False`.

To understand the reason for this you need to consider the data that Django is maintaining. `skip_unchanged` says to skip the row import when no changes are being made to the model table. When you change a M2M relationship the model table doesn't change. Instead the relationship table changes.

In your case you will have the following tables in the Django database:

- `<app>_writer` - All the authors.
- `<app>_book` - All the books.
- `<app>_book_writer` - The many-to-many relationships that link books with their writers.

When you import an existing book and only change the `writer` the only table that will be updated is `<app>_book_writer`. For some reason the import/export plugin doesn't consider this a change to the `book` model, so skips it.